# how is this code prone to sql injections?

Tags: node.js, express

I used this code in my simple project and  my supervisor told me it was insecure in terms of sql injections. how do I solve it?

```
const express = require('express')
const childProcess = require('child_process')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
       <h1>File viewer</h1>
       <form method='GET' action='/view'>
         <input name='filename' />
         <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
       </form>
   `)
})

app.get('/view', (req, res) => {
    const { filename } = req.query
    const child = childProcess.spawnSync('cat', [filename])

    if (child.status !== 0) {
        res.send(child.stderr.toString())
    } else {
        res.send(child.stdout.toString())
    }
})

app.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: Sanitize the `filename`.

Comment: Ask your supervisor to do his job and help you figure this out? What kind of move is it to just tell you that but not explain why.

Comment: Also ask your supervisor how they think _SQL_ injection is relevant here.

Comment: he actually told me to figure it out that is why am stuck

Comment: Why is us answering it okay but your manager answering it not? He should at least give you the context as to what SQL injection in and how sanitising the use input can mitigate it, then tell you to find the error while looking on. What a lazy supervisor.

Comment: i am really just looking for help. but then i have heard a new term "sanitize" how do i do that?

Comment: Maybe time to google "Sanitising User Input".